# Manually edit pallete for 16-colour Windows icon

Tags: colors, icons

I'm trying to create a 16-colour icon of the Lithuanian flag which requires the following 3 colours:

```
Top line = RGB(253,185,19)
Middle line = RGB(0,106,68)
Bottom line = RGB(193,39,45)
```

Black `RGB(0,0,0)` for text or border and White `RGB(255,255,255)` for background will also be required. By my calculations that is a total of 5 colours.

But when the image is converted to 16 colours in a program like `Greenfish Icon Editor Pro` or `Microsoft Paint`, the colours get corrupted to the nearest colour from the standard Windows 16-colour palette. For example, the top line gets moved to `RGB(255,255,0)`.

Is there an easy way to tell the icon to use specifically the required 5 colours only (and I don't care about the other 11)?

Comment: which image format are you using?

Comment: Why can't you use the regular 256-color or 32-bit modes?

Comment: @heavyd: Standard Windows icon (.ico).

Comment: @grawity: Well, 256-colour or 32-bit can be used, but it seems wasteful to have all the palette largely unused. If you're looking for a "better reason for trying to do this", then I might say that 16-colour icons are smaller and I'm going to be using these icons on a Windows CE device with only limited memory (which is all true)...but my main motivation is really to work out how to edit the colour palette :o)